# Remove Facebook code query parameter

Tags: facebook

I'm using Facebook authentification in my web app.

I have a URL of the type : https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=http://myapp.com/#story

It works really well but when the user is redirected to it, there's a query parameter that's added (for ex : http://myapp.com?code=AQCkHq--XXTngRCMgQxAAHExCaWzw5XYadd8vaVMytX91aPEc74oQWMBlyrr_HQUjBcC53sf_bREFz5cOBaFdgfvHSpWk1W0abbQA9ncbc0KQ0vyH6B1H37WXv1wcejblMQ6cTVLS98f4xvz-keiPgDJSh1v-Cyw-ACUFvAvs2yusHaSnfjITVZLDWQnNhBwpoELWFlJ75WAl0OrwD1_snZkQ2QQfL_5rcG2ZmpI9ORmFtFW-mrWEouA1zOiPSyTbP2d2LajGz82_KJuV5LBaFkULZ4mYSdALphPjvfwJkhrSQy7n_xKXGOfgr056bkqOIA#story;id=219012)

Is there a way to remove that long string from the URL?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you add the response_type=token parameter, it's gone. ;-)

Comment: Oh, but it doesn't go to the specific URL, but only to the base URL...